# Families of functions with "frequency is polynomial" property.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, polynomials, fourier-analysis

We know from Fourier analysis that we can write

$$f(nt)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kf(t)^k$$

For Fourier basis functions.

Probably the most famous example (special case):

$$n=0: \cos(0t) :\\ 1 = \sin(t)^2+\cos(t)^2$$

Often called the trigonometric unity or "trig-one".

Now to the question.. Can we find other families of functions other than sin, cos and exponential functions where this is also possible?

Comment: $e^{nt} = \left(e^t\right)^n$ :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes.. well except for complex exponential family maybe I should have written ;)